# Dart Angular sample

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, dart

I am using IntelliJ IDEA to develop a Dart/Angular app, from IDEA's new project wizard.

After compiling OK, I tried to load it both from browser (run as a local file) and from Web access (served by Apache2).

But the page (index.html) just show plain "Loading...", no further display etc.

Can anyone give some hint on this?

Comment: AFAIK loading from local file is not supposed to work due to Chrome browser security limitation. Are you using the router?

Comment: As I said, the file (or more precisely, the whole compiled output in `build` directory) was also served from Apache but still only showing "Loading..." and I am using Firefox, Chrome

Comment: But it's working in Dartium when launched from IDEA (without build)?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes, it does, though the loading is way SLOW...

Comment: Only the first time slow or also on successive reloads?

Comment: I don't know why loading the built application doesn't work.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer when launching in IDEA, following run and the first run do not have significant difference in loading time. I am running Windows 8.1 64bit.

Comment: Really hard to tell what could cause the problems. I'm not using Windows though.

Comment: This is embarrassing. I did some development with Dart and Polymer years back and did not face such funny issues. And now I have to struggle with no clear hope that this issue could be solved.

Comment: Anyway, will try later with my Linux machine.

Comment: Tried with my Linux machine, still the same issue: Ok to run in the IDE, the built-out code not working under Apache

Comment: I don't know. I don't have the time right now to try it myself. Which of the 3 available Angular2 templates did you use when you created the project?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Angula Web Application - a web app built using the latest stable version of Angular.

Comment: I'll have a look when I find time to try it myself. Could you please post the Dart version `dart --version` you're using?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have solved this problem.

Noticed there are a few lines in the output `index.html` in the `<script>...</script>` section:

```
<script>
    // WARNING: DO NOT set the <base href> like this in production!
    // Details: https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/router
    (function () {
        // App being served out of web folder (like WebStorm does)?
        var match = document.location.pathname.match(/^\/[_\w]+\/web\//);
        var href = match ? match[0] : '/';
        document.write('<base href="' + href + '" />');
    }());
</script>
```

Just comment out everything generated by the compiler.

One thing to notice is that: In IDEA I have checked to compile to "Production" and in command line the `pub help build` tells me the default `mode` is `release`, so I really wonder why these lines are not taken out when compiling to production release?

Comment: The production (release) mode refers to the generated JavaScript, not HTML or, say, image assets. Sorry for that confusion. Please follow / update [this IntelliJ/WebStorm bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14047) to see why we need that script there.